# What font is used for Cherished Lockets' logo?

Tags: font-identification

Anyone recognise the Font from [Cherished Lockets](http://www.cherishedlockets.co.uk)? I found this logo on Behance but not sure where exactly.

I have tried Identification tools and it didn't work because I have too little characters.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could find was **[Best-Cellar](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/throndsen/best-cellar/regular/)**

[image: Lockets]

The tools can't find id not becaus you have few characters, actually I've successfully identified tricky fonts at [What the Font!](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) with as few as 3 glyphs. It's all about **how much you can tell details apart**.

The provided image has very low resolution which hardens the process of identification quite a lot, I was able to find a higher res one but the text was too mixed up with the background, extracting it leaded me to Best Cellar, but clear differences in certain glyphs shows that this isn't the exact same font.

But it is the closest i could find without getting straight into asking the brand owner about it.

Comment: when suggesting a font please keep in mind we require a screenshot of the font you recommend.